# use of 'this' with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, this

I'm building a backbone.js app with facebook api and phonegap.

In my User model, I'm trying to attach a listener to see when the user has logged in.

```
Myapp.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
            console.log('logged-in event');
            this.get_me();

        });
    },
    get_me: function(){
    console.log('use the api to get user details');
    }
});
```

of course, when I do this, the `this` is (I believe) attached to FB, not Myapp. 
I've tried

```
var this_user = this;
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response,this_user){
   this_user.get_user();
}
```

but that still fails.

I've read all sorts of blogs on how to use `this`, but can't seem to get one that I actually understand when working with multiple objects and how do I refer back to the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work, but note this part:

```
var this_user = this;
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response,this_user){
   this_user.get_user();
}
```

The `this_user` parameter should not be in the anonymous function declaration. That's because Facebook never passes the second parameter in the callback, so it ends up being `null`; in fact, you should have received a JS error on the `this_user.get_user()` statement.

```
var this_user = this;
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
   this_user.get_user();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var this_user = this;
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response,this_user){
   this_user.get_user();
}
```

That `this_user` lookup won't resolve to its parent scope as you have an argument with the same name. Change one or the other.

Comment: The first example posted didn't have a second parameter at all. I would think that the `this_user` parameter to the subscribe callback should just be removed.

Comment: @Cory Yeah, that's what I would go with.

Comment: @Cory you were correct, the this_user shouldn't have been in the callback at all. As Jack said below. Thanks for the help.